# How can I cause a web browser to use 50% CPU

Tags: javascript, performance, testing

I am working with JavaScript and I want to test the performance of my script when the browser has heavy load. The method I'd like to employ is to have a script run that would cause the browser to use 50% CPU (of a single core of course) and than I would judge whether or not the script's performance is acceptable. My script draws on a canvas at the position of the cursor, so simple numbers from Firefox's and Chrome's developer tools aren't sufficient enough to gauge responsiveness.

Currently I know the code below will cause 100% CPU usage, how can I make it only use 50%?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    while (loop = true) {
        loop = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You could try different `setInterval` loop speeds

Comment: Use [Request Animation Frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @sarbbottam: it will not be called on a minimized tab

Comment: @Coffee'd Up Hacker: these days browsers run different tabs as separated processes. So do you want to make the current tab with your script busy or some other tab?

Comment: @zerkms: [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) needs to incorporated too.

Comment: @sarbbottam: `requestAnimationFrame` will not be called anyway.

Comment: @zerkms: Firefox is still not capable of using multiple CPU cores, so I want only the current tab to cause whatever core it's on to jump to around 50% CPU usage.

Comment: @Coffee'd Up Hacker: so you want your exact script to experience insufficient of CPU time resource?

Comment: @zerkms: I don't know what you mean by that :-/ Basically, though, I want something that does what a infinite while loop does, but at half the speed/performance. Irrelevant to the hardware capabilities.

Comment: @Coffee'd Up Hacker: from your question it's not clear what you want to load. Just a CPU core. A browser process. A particular browser tab.

Comment: @zerkms: I want to start a JavaScript file with a piece of code that would cause the browser to use 50% of a CPU core. I would then add the rest of my script after it to see how the script performs with the added stress from that 50% CPU usage.

Comment: @Coffee'd Up Hacker: your script will not be affected by CPU load if it runs in the same tab, because javascript is single threaded. So it doesn't matter if it will be 50% or 200% or 10% load. What matters is how long it takes.

Comment: @zerkms: Oh, right. Like what comes after it will only run after the loop is complete? (which would be never.)

Comment: @zerkms: You should answer my initial question with that, so I can give you best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as it is asked now could be answered as: as soon as JS is single threaded - it means it doesn't matter how much CPU an arbitrary loop consumes. Just because what runs after - runs after, when CPU is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a small library for leveraging the problem you describe, you can however alter it to consume 50 % of CPU to test whether your application remains running at the smoothness you'd like to.

It's basically a "thread manager" (where a thread is an instance of a heavy operation which has been written to run in iterations, so it can be halted whenever the CPU needs to do other things, such as render UI or run other script operations). You could create a thread that never finishes and set the manager priority to 50% to mimic the situation you describe in your question.

It's on GitHub with documentation and a basic example which you should be able to easily adjust to do the above:

https://github.com/igorski/zThreader